# nodejs prepending to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

For Node.js, what is the best way to prepend to a file in a way SIMILAR to

```
fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app.log'), 'appendme', 'utf8')
```

Personally, the best way really revolves around a asynchronous solution to create a log where I can basically push onto the file from the top.

Comment: Define "best" - What is your requirement? Are you talking about best practice when creating a log? Doing this asynchronously?

Comment: Personally, the best way really revolves around a synchronous solution to create a log where I can basically push onto the file from the top.

Comment: In that case you should make it clear because imho doing blocking i/o in node for logging is a _horrible_ idea outside of a very very specific context.

Comment: Wow..I can't believe why I said synchronous, i meant the asynchronous. Silly mistake.

Comment: Another option would be to read the contents of the file then prepend that data with your new data then write to that file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is impossible to add to a beginning of a file. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652436/c-file-streams-appending-at-the-beggining) for the similar problem in C or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343044/c-prepending-to-beginning-of-a-file) for the similar problem in C#.

I suggest you do your logging in the conventional way (that is, log to the end of file).

Otherwise, there is no way around reading the file, adding the text to the start and writing it back to the file which can get really costly really fast.

Answer (score 17):

This solution isn't mine and I don't know where it's from but it works.

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('message.txt')
const fd = fs.openSync('message.txt', 'w+')
const insert = Buffer.from("text to prepend \n")
fs.writeSync(fd, insert, 0, insert.length, 0)
fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length, insert.length)
fs.close(fd, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Great answer - this does indeed work. I used this to prepend a byte-order marker to CSVs I was creating so that Excel would not screw up the encoding on certain characters.

Comment: Awesome!  This works well.  btw. `Buffer()` is deprecated - use `Buffer.from()` in the above code.

Answer (score 8):

It seems it is indeed possible with https://www.npmjs.com/package/prepend-file

Comment: Note: That does not work as advertized - the complexity of the operation depends on the file size - prepending to a 4gb file will copy 4gb of data around.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it was advertised as prepending to a file and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Well, it probably works as advertised, but in some cases is not going to be a good idea!

Comment: I agree with @BenjaminGruenbaum: this is not "prepending" this is copying the entire file in order to 'prepend'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to prepend text to a file using gulp and a custom built function.

```
var through = require('through2');

gulp.src('somefile.js')
     .pipe(insert('text to prepend with'))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('Destination/Path/'))


function insert(text) {
    function prefixStream(prefixText) {
        var stream = through();
        stream.write(prefixText);
        return stream;
    }

    let prefixText = new Buffer(text + "\n\n"); // allocate ahead of time

    // creating a stream through which each file will pass
    var stream = through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
        //console.log(file.contents.toString());

        if (file.isBuffer()) {
            file.contents = new Buffer(prefixText.toString() + file.contents.toString());
        }

        if (file.isStream()) {
            throw new Error('stream files are not supported for insertion, they must be buffered');
        }

        // make sure the file goes through the next gulp plugin
        this.push(file);
        // tell the stream engine that we are done with this file
        cb();
    });

    // returning the file stream
    return stream;    
}
```

Sources: `[cole_gentry_github_dealingWithStreams][1]`

Answer (score 0):

Its possible by using the `prepend-file` node module. Do the following:

1. `npm i prepend-file -S`
2. import `prepend-file module` in your respective code.

Example:

```js
let firstFile = 'first.txt';
let secondFile = 'second.txt';
prependFile(firstFile, secondFile, () => {
  console.log('file prepend successfully');
})
```

Comment: Hey Chandra, can you please explain what the `-S` option for the `npm install` command does? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Comment: @SalmonKiller Prior to [npm-5](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), `npm install` would just install the package without adding it to your `package.json` file. `-S` is short for `--save`. Starting with npm-5, this option is called `-P` or `--save-prod`. You would use `--no-save` if you didn’t want the package added to `package.json` (i.e., it’s now opt-out).

Answer (score 0):

This method can also be an alternative:

```
fs.readFile(path.dirname(__filename) + '/read.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  fs.writeFile(path.dirname(__filename) + '/read.text', 'prepend text' + data, (err) => {
        
  })
});
```